# Is it possible to determine distance travel based on time for a calculated route

Tags: here-api

From a route returned in Nokia maps, is it possible to determine distance traveled based on time, using the speed limits of the returned route. I would like to find the position along the returned route in lat and long.
In other words I would like to start at a known point, travel 60 minutes along the route, and know the point I will be at. Then be able to repeat this for the entire route.

Answer (score 1):

Keep a log of how much time you have accounted for. For the `timeTravelled` -

- Subtract the time take for each `leg` until you are on the current leg.
- On the current leg, subtract the time take for each `manuever` until you are on the current manuever
- On the current manuever, take the Nth coordinate of the current `shape` so that the remainder of the time is accounted for

There are no times associated with the `shape` information, so the  assumption here is that each coordinate is evenly spaced. So if you need to account for 40% of the time of the current manuever then you can assume that you have covered 40% of the `shape`.

Something like this:

```
 function estimateLocation (myRoute, timeTravelled){
      var timeSoFar = 0,
      currentLeg = 0,
      currentManeuver = 0;

    while ( timeSoFar +  myRoute.legs[currentLeg].travelTime < timeTravelled){
      timeSoFar +=  myRoute.legs[currentLeg].travelTime;
      currentLeg++
    }

    while ( timeSoFar +  myRoute.legs[currentLeg].maneuvers[currentManeuver].travelTime < timeTravelled){
      timeSoFar +=  myRoute.legs[currentLeg].maneuvers[currentManeuver].travelTime;
      currentManeuver++;
    }

    console.log(currentLeg, currentManeuver);


    var shapeIndex = Math.floor((timeTravelled - timeSoFar) *  myRoute.legs[currentLeg].maneuvers[currentManeuver].shape.getLength()/ myRoute.legs[currentLeg].maneuvers[currentManeuver].travelTime);
    return (myRoute.legs[currentLeg].maneuvers[currentManeuver].shape.get(shapeIndex));
    }
```